# Persist Inferred Schema from Pyspark Dataframe to File on S3

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a JSON file that I need to stream, thus I need to declare the schema upfront. The file has over 300 columns so I'd like to read in the data and infer the schema, save that schema file (in whatever format works) to S3, and then going forward stream the files while using that schema file to define the streaming schema.

What I've done thus far is:

```
read_df = spark.read.load(inputPath, format='json', inferSchema=True)
my_schema = read_df.schema
```

At this point I've tried to extract the schema via `my_schema.json`, which apparently is a `StructType` but I don't know how to persist it to S3. `my_schema.jsonValue()` outputs a JSON but again, I'm not sure how to write it to S3. I tried this:

```
with open("/dbfs:/my-mounted_drive/my_schema.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(my_schema.jsonValue(), f)
```

This code gives me this error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

If I change the path to the following it doesn't error out but I can't find the file.

```
with open("my_schema.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(my_schema.jsonValue(), f)
```

I'm pretty agnostic to how I accomplish the solution, but perfect flow would be *read and infer -> save to S3 -> stream data where* `schema=<myfile>`

There are a few similar questions but no duplicates, and furthermore none of those solutions work for me.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbutils` put method with syntax below

```
 dbutils.fs.put(s"/mnt/" + MountName, json.dump(my_schema.jsonValue()))
```

Considering you have valid mount name in `MountName`